# Best concise method to linearize list of map values?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've a List of Map like this:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> l = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("X", 1);
m.put("Y", 9);
l.add(m);
m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("X", 23);
m.put("Y", 6);
l.add(m);
```

What is the best method to linearize all map values with lambda primitives to obtain a list like this

```
List<Integer> = [1, 9, 23, 6]
```

?

Comment: The code does not compile

Comment: Since `HashMap` does not guaranty any order, there is no guaranty to get `1, 9, 23, 6` when converting all map values to a list. And the list should be `List<Map<String,Integer>>` instead of `List<Map<String,Object>>`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
List<Integer> result = l
        .stream()
        .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result); // [1, 9, 23, 6]
```

Comment: refer to the comment by Holger as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665184/best-concise-method-to-linearize-list-of-map-values#comment92260259_52665184

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can do it without streams (but with lambdas):

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
yourListOfMaps.forEach(map -> result.addAll(map.values());
```

The list of maps should be of type `List<Map<String, Integer>>`.